# Installing gcc49 with Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, gcc4.9

I'm trying to get Homebrew to install `gcc49` (GCC 4.9). Specifically, I'm installing using the command,

```
brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49
```

However, doing this normally, I get an error saying that I'm missing `gmp4`. This is where it gets weird.

If I then do `brew install homebrew/versions/gmp4`, I'm informed once again that `gmp4` is missing. The library doesn't install. The exact same thing happens for a few other required libraries. Right now, rather than fixing this strange behaviour, I'm trying to run

```
brew install homebrew/versions/gcc48 --with homebrew/versions/gmp4 --with homebrew/versions/libmpc08 --with homebrew/versions/mpfr2 --with homebrew/versions/cloog018 --with homebrew/versions/isl011
```

... Which results in

```
==> Installing dependencies for gcc48: gmp4, mpfr2, libmpc08, isl011, cloog018
==> Installing gcc48 dependency: gmp4
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gmplib.org/pub/gmp/gmp-5.1.3.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file gmp-h.in
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/5.1.3 --enable-cxx
==> make
==> make check
==> make install
Error: Empty installation
```

It's that last line that really confuses me. I've never seen that returned by any software I've tried to install - what's going on, and how can I fix it?

Interestingly enough, when I try this on my desktop, which has the same Homebrew version, GCC 4.9 installs without a problem by simply running `brew install gcc49`, without even having to go through `homebrew/versions`.

Comment: what happens if you first do `brew tap homebrew/versions` and then `brew install gcc49`?

Comment: @Pouya You should make this comment into an answer. It worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @MattLong, I did as you suggested. Happy it help `:)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to do

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
```

first, and then

```
brew install gcc49
```

If you go to the buttom of [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions) page, you can find what I mentioned above.

> `brew tap` allows you to add more Github repos to the list of formulae
>   that brew tracks, updates and installs from. When naming tap repos and
>   formulas, however, there are a few gotchas to beware of...

Read more [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/brew-tap).

Comment: Updated url for the `brew tap` command: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/brew-tap.md

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is now deprecated; the official way to install former versions of gcc is:

`brew install gcc@4.9`

See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/1472.

Comment: Can you back this answer up with a source? I don't have a Mac to test this out at this point.

Comment: I think the command is given by brew itself when you try to install it the old way, but I've included a link to the relevant pull request.

Comment: How can I create links without version number like `gcc` and `g++` in /usr/local/bin for versioned formulas?